# Using the definition of congruence and Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm currently working on this problem:

---

Use the definition of congruence and Fermat's Little Theorem  to show that if gcd$(b,561) = 1$, then $$b^{560} \equiv
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    1 &\text{ mod } 3,\\
    1 &\text{ mod } 11,\\
1 &\text{ mod } 17.\\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$$

Conclude that, if gcd$(b,561)=1$, then $b^{560}\equiv1\text{ mod }561$ and so $561$ is a Carmichael number. Hint: What does it mean that $b^{561}\equiv 1\text{ mod }561?$

---

So I'm guessing that it's significant that 3,11, and 17 all divide 561. Fermat's little theorem doesn't, by itself, provide for something like $b^{p-1} \equiv 1\text{ mod }q$ where q and p are different, so I'm guessing this is where I need to use congruence to prove that 561 is congruent to 3, 11, and 17?

Comment: Yes, 561= 3(11)(17).  It follows from that that if gcd(b, 561)= 1 then gcd(b, 3)= 1, gcd(b, 11)= 1, and gcd(b, 17)= 1.

Comment: Hint, because $561=3\cdot 11 \cdot 17$, where $3,11,17$ all are primes, you will have things like
$$b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \rightarrow (b^2)^{280} \equiv 1^{280} \pmod{3}$$
$$b^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \rightarrow (b^{10})^{56} \equiv 1^{56} \pmod{11}$$
$$b^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17} \rightarrow (b^{16})^{35} \equiv 1^{35} \pmod{17}$$
or
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $ 561 = 3*11*17 $ the smallest Carmichael number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433029/why-is-561-31117-the-smallest-carmichael-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $561=3\cdot 11 \cdot 17$, where $3,11,17$ all are primes, you will have things like
$$b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \rightarrow (b^2)^{280} \equiv 1^{280} \pmod{3}$$
$$b^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11} \rightarrow (b^{10})^{56} \equiv 1^{56} \pmod{11}$$
$$b^{16} \equiv 1 \pmod{17} \rightarrow (b^{16})^{35} \equiv 1^{35} \pmod{17}$$
or
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$$
$$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$$
or
$$b^{560} - 1 =3q_1$$
$$b^{560} - 1 =11q_2$$
$$b^{560} - 1 =17q_3$$
and applying [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) two times for $3q_1=11q_2=17q_3$ $$b^{560} - 1 =561q$$
or $$b^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod{561}$$