# smallest Carmichael number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, carmichael-numbers

I know already that:

If $m = p \cdot q \cdot r$ with $p \neq q \neq r$ prime and $p-1, q-1, r-1 \mid m-1$, then m is a Carmichael number.

And Carmichael numbers are the product of at least 3 different odd prime numbers.

How can I easily find the smallest Carmichael number with this information?

I know that this question is already answered before, but I think there has to be an easier way then it was done there. [Why is $ 561 = 3*11*17 $ the smallest Carmichael number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433029/why-is-561-31117-the-smallest-carmichael-number)

Comment: I mean, a raw search takes very little time.

Comment: I did a research. But I wasn't be able to find an easy way to find the smallest Carmichael number. Maybe I am wrong, and there just isn't an easier way.

Comment: Again, a raw search is extremely easy.  Pencil and paper easy.  I don't know what more you could want...it's certainly a plausible guess that $3$ divides the smallest one, which happens to be true, but maybe that is pure chance.  After all the next $6$ are prime to $3$.

Comment: Unless I blundered, the next one divisible by $3$ is the $14^{th}$, $62745$.   That surprises me a bit.  After all, you get the condition $2\,|\,(n-1)$ for free.  But I guess that's just how it plays out.

Comment: @lulu Extremely easy is exaggerated, but to find the smallest is in fact not too diffficult.

Comment: @LauravanLeuven Why do you think that there is an easier way ? You already know that we must have only odd prime factors, at least $3$ and a Carmichael number is squarefree. This leaves quite few possibilities not exceeding $561$ which have to be tested.

Comment: @Peter  True.  Well, my guess that it was divisible by $3$ sped things up a lot.  But that really seems to have been sheer luck.

Comment: What helps is that there cannot be prime factors $p,q$ with $p\mid q-1$. This is an important property of Carmichael numbers !

Comment: Well in the link "Why is 561=3∗11∗17 the smallest Carmichael number?", the person who answered the question did it very extensive. First he assumed that one prime factor is 3, then 5, etc. But I think that the only option left is then indeed to do it by brute force, or not? It's not a pretty way, but it is at least better then the way it was done in that extensive answer.

Comment: A little brute force is inevitable. Once $561$ is found, we can quickly finished since already $7\cdot 11\cdot 13$ is larger. If the smallest prime factor is $5$, the cofactor must be less than $113$ and $11$ cannot be a prime factor. This only leaves the possibility $5\cdot 7\cdot 13$. A little more work is necessary for the case that the smallest prime factor is $3$.